# Cartesian product to get set of indices to point to unique elements in NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Whats a good way to get combinations of indices that points to unique elements in array. For example `a = [1,1,3,2]`, the possible set of pointers would be `{0,2,3}, {1,2,3}`.

I can use `argsort` in combination with splitting the elements by frequency to then use something like `itertools.product` to get all sets of indices I want.

This is what I tried:

```
from numpy import array, split
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
from itertools import product
a = array([1,1,3,2])
fq = itemfreq(a)[:,1]
fq = [int(f + sum(fq[:i])) for i, f in enumerate(fq)]
print list(product(*(ptrs for ptrs in split(a.argsort(), fq) if len(ptrs))))
#> [(0, 3, 2), (1, 3, 2)]
```

How can I do this better?

Comment: On a personal level, please use `from numpy import array, split` instead of `from pylab import *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does get you the indices, but possibly not in the format you want:

```
[np.where(a==x) for x in np.unique(a)]

[(array([0, 1]),), (array([3]),), (array([2]),)]
```

I imagine there is a better way, without the for loop.

Comment: Thanks, this is better than mine, maybe this can be improved somehow, I can get the format I want by using this: `print list(product(*(np.where(a==x)[0] for x in np.unique(a))))`

Comment: @Joelmob: This answer combined with your suggested edit is what I had in my answer, but the essential idea here is the same as mine, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks @Warren. This was also the same, but shorter: `list(product(*(a[a==x] for x in np.unique(a))))`

Comment: @Joelmob: I don't understand that suggestion; `a[a==x]` gives the *values* from `a`, not their indices.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser sorry I don't know what happened, I tested with `a[a==x]` and I got the output I wanted. But now I see that this is wrong so `a[a==x]` wasn't right.

Answer (score 1):

@atomh33ls's answer can be vectorized as follows.

First, extract the inverse indices and counts of each unique item. If you are using numpy >= 1.9:

```
_, idx, cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```

In older versions, this does the same:

```
_, idx = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
cnt = np.bincount(idx)
```

And now, a little bit of magic and, voila:

```
>>> np.split(np.arange(len(a))[np.argsort(idx)], np.cumsum(cnt)[:-1])
[array([0, 1]), array([3]), array([2])]
```